# Diferencia de fechas utilizando un DF como guia de dias habiles

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

Cominidad, espero esten muy bien

tengo un DF (dias_hab) que contiene los dias habiles en un rango de tiempo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven excluye fectivos, sabados y domingos

ahora - tengo otro df con el que requiero calcular los dias habiles entre dos fechas, sin embargo, en el ejemplo de la fila 3 el resultado deberia ser 10 dias hab descontando el festivo colombia 4 de julio, sabados y domingos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que he intentado aplicar es llevar a sql los df asi:

dias_hab = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['Date'])

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- el resultado de process 2_1 me genera este error:
  PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: dd

intente cambiar el dd por el df de dias habiles para que me tomara como intervalo pero claramente no funciono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo para mi debió funcionar  la instrucción DateDiff con el dd pero no lo hizo, creo que python no toma esa función  y aun asi
** No se como enlazar el dataframe de dias habiles a esa consulta para que evalue los dias habiles basados en ese intervalo que le ingresó, por que si la fecha inicio empieza antes del intervalo, esperaria en la columna que me retorna solo los dias habiles del intervalo - mes evaluado - (ejemplo de lo que espero retorne)

basado en este calendario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el resultado esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor coloa el código como texto y lee [ask] y [example]

Answer (score 0):

Particularmente yo no utilizaría una lista con los laborables. Creo que me sería más sencillo utilizar los festivos pero utilizando tu planteamiento a nivel datos puedes hacer algo tan sencillo como esto:

```
def obtener_dias_habiles(row):
    mascara = dias_hab[row['finicial'] <= dias_hab['Date']]
    mascara = mascara[mascara['Date'] <= row['ffinal']]
    return len(mascara)
```

o de manera más cómoda:

```
def obtener_dias_habiles(row):
    return len(dias_hab[(row['finicial'] <= dias_hab['Date']) & (dias_hab['Date'] <= row['ffinal'])])
```

La función obtener_dias_habiles crea una máscara sobre el dataframe dias_hab que cumpla con dos condiciones:

`row['finicial'] <= dias_hab['Date']` y `dias_hab['Date'] <= row['ffinal']`

Es decir, se queda únicamente con los días hábiles entre `finicial` y `ffinal`.

Si recuperamos con `len` la longitud de esa máscara aplicándola sobre el dataframe `dias_hab` tendremos el total de días hábiles entre esas dos fechas.

Construimos una columna nueva con el resultado del `apply` y listo.

```
df['dias_habiles'] = df.apply(obtener_dias_habiles, axis=1)
```